# How to upload a file, if you have the file url, to S3 using an S3 presigned url?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a url of an external image. I want to upload that image file to S3.

My react code looks something like this:

```
fetch(imageUrl)
  .then(async (res) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post('api/create-upload-url', {
      key: filename,
      bucket: bucketName,
      contentType: 'image/jpg',
    })

    await axios.put(data.url, res.body, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    })
  })
```

It is uploading an empty object to the bucket:

```
{}
```

Comment: may need to use aws-skd to accomplish this, see https://scanskill.com/aws/upload-files-amazon-s3-using-presigned-urls/, one many articles online.

Comment: I've come across a similar issue in GCS where the problem turned out to be not including the ```Content-Type``` header on the upload request. Maybe adding that might help here?